# Want to display more information when i click on see more button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

when i click on `See more` I want to display more information

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you using compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a state for expand/collapse to change max lines visible to user. Using `Modifier.animateContentSize()` will result smooth size change with animation.
Result

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ExpandableComposable() {
    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Column() {
        Row {
            Text("Price")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            Text(text = "120.0 QR")
        }

        Row() {
            Text("Rating")
        }

        Text("Product Summary", fontSize = 18.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        Text(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor " +
                    "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis" +
                    " nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." +
                    " Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum " +
                    "dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat " +
                    "non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
            maxLines = if (!expanded) 3 else Int.MAX_VALUE,
            modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()
        )

        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End) {
            TextButton(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
                Text(text = if (expanded) "Show less" else "Show more")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have these xml properties of the **TextView** and **Button**

```
<TextView
    ........
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:singleLine="false" /> 
 
<Button
   .........
   android:text="See more"
   android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

and inside your Activity **onCreate**

```
    TextView txt;
    Button btShowmore;
          @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                txt=findViewById(R.id.textview);
                btShowmore=findViewById(R.id.btShowmore);
                btShowmore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

               if (btShowmore.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("See more"))
                        {
                            txt.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);//your TextView
                            btShowmore.setText("See less");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txt.setMaxLines(3);//your TextView
                            btShowmore.setText("See more");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: What if the for some content if the text is not very long? Still showing show more doesnt makes sense.